# How to resolve edittext hide issue when numeric keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app which is used for tablets only in landscape mode. In one of my screens i am using custom dialog with edittext and when user types in edittext, the numeric keypad covers all the edittext so user can't able to see what he/she is typing in edittext. I've used the imeOptions but that didn't work out. Please suggest any other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use "adjustResize" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

From the documentation:

> "adjustResize" The activity's main window is always resized to make
>   room for the soft keyboard on screen.
>
> "adjustPan" The activity's main window is not resized to make room for
>   the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
>   automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
>   the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
>   generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
>   close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
>   the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```